# Accessing root files by logging in as normal user

Tags: permissions, root

After logging in as a root from a terminal, I can create new directories but I can neither see nor manually access them by mouse clicking when log in as normal user in GUI. I can only access them through terminal. Why is this so?

Comment: Don't log in as root directly.

Comment: How do you log in as root? Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: I want to do some work regarding IPC and FIFOs. So that's why I need to log in as root.

Comment: I logged in as root using su - command followed by password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desktop is running under normal user and not as root user that is why you can access files created by root only via terminal